How does the gas boiler call for heat work?
Context
I have a Main/Baxi Eco Elite 25 Combi ErP Methane boiler. Really want to get rid of it in favour of a heat pump, but I am stuck with it for now.
I have put the call for heat signal onto a Shelly 1 Mini Gen3 relay. When the relay is on, the boiler heats the radiators as expected. This is great for controlling via Home Assistant.
Recently, however, the boiler stopped calling for heat for no apparent reason. I removed the relay and physically connected the signal wires together, but still no call for heat. Left it some time, but no change. I then put the relay back the way I had it, turned the main boiler physical switch off and went to bed. Then, while I was on the phone to Baxi, it just mysteriously started working! Since then, it has been on for several hours without fault.
I have two hypotheses for this;

my boiler has developed sentience and knows when I am calling Baxi.
the house heating control automation that I (foolishly) enabled at 2am found an edge case and toggled the relay so quickly that the boiler got "upset".

I think the latter is more likely, though I have no way to prove this.
I would, therefore, like to build in failsafes into my automation to ensure that I do not damage the boiler. For example, the automation currently runs whenever someone enters or leaves a room, so perhaps this is too frequently for the boiler. Would it be better to only run the automation every x minutes?
Motivation
We have

methane boiler
electric radiators
an Electricity supplier who

sometimes offers negative electricity prices (yes, negative, they really do pay us to use electricity!).
provides half-hourly pricing data via their API.



Adding the boiler to Home Assistant enables us to heat the house using

electricity, when electricity is cheaper than gas.
gas, when electricity is more expensive than gas.

Saving money like this will help me to be able to get that heat pump!
Questions

How does the call for heat work?
Does the call for heat have a minimum amount of time that it must be off for?
Does the call for heat have a maximum amount of time that it can be on for?

I am not looking for help with Home Assistant. I do, however, need to broaden my understanding of a boiler that was designed for a differnt time.
Attempts so far

I called Main/Baxi who advised that because I am not a Gas Safe registered engineer and I am using an external controller, I should speak to a local heating engineer.
I emailed Shelly UK support, who advised me to wire it like any other load, but this resulted in the 2A fuses blowing.


Most home heaters usually use some type of thermostat that calls for heat or turn off.  Some like boilers have two.  One to keep the water hot and one to pass heat to the house.

I replaced the old thermostat as it was useless. The Shelly relay performs the same function, only without the thermometer. I put several WiFi thermometers throughout the house instead.

If you have cast iron hot water radiators, you can't use room occupancy as an input to controlling them. They don't react that fast.  You can buy controllers that learn the reactivity of your whole system (radiators and house working together) and use weather sensors or predictions to manage boiler temperature and preheat.  At least for that aspect of this system you should not program it yourself. There are decades of experience in commercial controllers.

I am aware of those expensive controllers, but I already have home assistant and the relay. I use occupancy sensors to turn off rooms I that are not in use and it does work well. As I say, this question is specifically relating to the workings of the call for heat mechanism, nothing else.

Good luck finding a gas engineer who can deal with anything out of the ordinary on the electrical side (even fitting a new boiler to slightly uncommon wiring is enough to confuse many of them).  And Gas Safe is irrelevant if you're just working on the electrics.

... I suspect that their service line just won't talk to anyone who's not qualified to do the gas side

Yet another reason to get a heat pump and solar panels!

I got the solar panels (and battery) earlier this year so I started looking (again) at my own controls. But it's cheaper to sell electricity at 12p/kWh - not the best, but the best I could get given my lock in on the supply side - and buy gas for heating at a little over half that. Still, for 8 months of the year I'm not just covering all my electricity needs, and selling to the grid, but reducing my use of gas. I decided to prioritise saving for a heat pump over the cost and effort of what I would have needed to do

While I can't say that toggling the call for heat really fast (faster than humanly possible) doesn't ever cause problems, toggling it as quickly as a human can move a thermostat back and forth definitely doesn't. All boilers/controllers I've had can handle that and need to because listening for the click repeatedly is reasonable in testing.  They should also be able to debounce a vibrating switch transition so I very much doubt you confused it that way.
I've repaired a heating controller by replacing the relay that calls for heat; apart from an uncommon pinout they're nothing special.  I've also done temporary full-manual workarounds while waiting for parts.
I've had similar project thoughts to you (though more around hot water; heating improvements would be a nice extra), but can never justify the time. If you've designed any control systems, as I have, you'll  know that while not trivial, central heating control is not particularly complicated either.
As a working hypothesis, your boiler is simply acting up.  Hopefully just a glitch but my old one was prone to bad solder joints on the main circuit board.  I replaced the board once, and resoldered quite a few dodgy joins on a coupe of other occasions.  Unresponsiveness that was sometimes fixed by slow power cycling was exactly the sort of thing it did then.  However it might be a good idea to enable some sort of timeout on the call for heat.  To get it back to human timescales, not toggling it more than once a second would be feasible.  That's far faster than you'd need it to respond to any real conditions.

Great answer, thank you. Do you know if there is a maximum time that the call to heat can be on for?

Also, it stopped wroking again a few hours ago. I turned it off entirely for those few hours, as you suggested, and now it is back on. Frustrating!

@JamesGeddes I've never found a maximum (and of course everything varies between brands) but of course in normal operation it could be several hours warming a house up from having been empty and cold, or after a power cut. It does seem like (as in your case) heating failures are more common when the weather turns cold. TBH this was more of a collection of relevant things I've picked up than a full answer.

first your statement of I have a hypothesis of my boiler has developed sentience and knows when I am calling Baxi.
definition of sentience is the the capacity of to experience feelings and have cognitive abilities, encompasses the ability to evaluate actions, remember consequences, assess risks and benefits, and have a degree of awareness.
mostly a poor word choice if you believe your boiler has feelings & awareness.  If you think the boiler controls are such that it can remember past actions and an employs some algorithmic hysteresis/PID control function, which is possible with today's electronics then it would be printed in the advertisement/manual of those controls.

how does a call for heat work

a thermostat, in a given heating zone, measures temperature in the room and when it goes below a set point on the stat, it calls for heat by connecting/closing an electrical circuit between the stat and the boiler controller.  When the controller on the boiler sees this call for heat electrical signal then that boiler controller fires the boiler; other things also happen in the overall control scheme of when the boiler should fire (low water cutoff in boiler ok, zone valves open, etc). which depends on what the heating system is comprised of.

Does the call for heat have a minimum amount of time that it must be off for?

That depends on the boiler controller.  There are many, so you would have to look it up there.

I would like to build in failsafes into my automation to ensure that I do not damage the boiler. For example, the automation currently runs whenever someone enters or leaves a room, so perhaps this is too frequently for the boiler. Would it be better to only run the automation every x minutes?

you need to understand fundamentals first before going into "automation".  What I mention is based on what I know in northeast U.S.  If you're in UK (given you ppl drive on the wrong side of the road :) I don't know what may or may not be similar conventionally for residential heating.
And then you mention you want to build in failsafes to "your automation".  Fundamentally the conventional automation of a thermostat the failsafes are already built in.  You seem to be insinuating best I can interpret on some extra kind of heating control automation that is also comprised of being able to remotely change your thermostat setting from your phone via a homeassistant app.  That is not "automation" and in regards to "failsafe" you really want to trust when or not your heating system will work based on some internet app - the failsafe would not to be used one given all the data breaches that happen so often.

need to broaden my understanding of a boiler that was designed for a different time.

I find this funny.  how old is your boiler?
and for "automation" at best there is something like a NEST thermostat which has a built in algorithm that attempts to calculate the most efficient/comfortable heating schedule based off past calls for heat and what happens with room temperature over time, as opposed to the simple "room temp goes below a certain temp = call for heat until it rises to or # ° above set point.

I think you will find that we had roads before you had a country ;)

that response made my day, you're ok

I'm here all week ;)

I do appreciate that off the shelf solutions exist, however, they do not allow me to do the fine-grained control that I need, such as switching energy source. I am asking for details about the workings and requirements of the call for heat system.

Also, side note, our oldest road is about 5000 years old. https://www.nationaltrail.co.uk/en_GB/the-ridgeway/itinerary/the-ridgeway-a-walk-on-britains-oldest-road/ Almost as old as "yo momma" (I hear that is funny in the USA?)
